# Access R,G,B values using python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, rgba

Apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere, I looked at a few suggestions but didn't find a match.
I am trying to get the RGB values for each pixel in a png image. Based on the pillow access documentation (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html#pixelaccess) I tried the following:

```
def image_vec(fname):
  im = Image.open(fname)
  pix = im.load()
  x, y = im.size
  for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
       print(pix[i, j])
```

The documentation example seems to suggest that I should expect a triplet when I call pix[i,j]. However the snippet above prints out a quadruplet like so:

```
 (182, 183, 172, 255)
 (206, 206, 197, 255)
 (156, 155, 148, 248)
```

So what are these values I am looking at? Is it R, G, B, alpha? If so isn't the alpha value supposed to be between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those values are the R, G, B, alphas of the pixel.
Here the alpha range from 0 to 255, where 255 is completely opaque and 0 is completely transparent.